# Why does "never auto-play" video in Safari often fail to work?

Tags: safari, audio, video

In Safari version 16.4 running on macOS 13.3.1, in the Preferences ▹ Websites tab, I have selected "Never Auto-Play" in the pull-down menu in the bottom right.
[image]
I've had it that way for some time, and have restarted Safari since changing it. Nevertheless, some websites still manage to auto-play video ads. Here is a concrete example; I don't mean to call out this specific site, but providing an actual example seems relevant to the question of how a site can circumvent the don't-auto-play feature:
[image]
Thus, the "never auto-play" setting works on many sites, but fails on some. **Is there more that I need to do to disable video (and audio) auto-play**? Perhaps there is another Safari setting that I should check?

Comment: Go to menu bar from Safari. From here, go to Debug > Media Flags > Disallow Inline Video. And turn this setting on. What does it do? This is working for me.

Comment: If you don't have the Debug option in Safari, run `defaults write com.apple.safari IncludeInternalDebugMenu 1` in Terminal.

Comment: @Thinkr Thanks. I went ahead and tried it, and restarted Safari, but unfortunately there is no change in the autoplay behavior.